# Why the compiler is generating errors which aren't errors at all

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-errors, crafting-interpreters

I was trying to write my own VM implementation in C++ from the excellent book [Crafting Interpreters](https://craftinginterpreters.com/).

The book builds a stack based virtual machine, of which I am writing a C++ version

So here is the code where the compiler is yelling at me.

object.h

```cpp
#pragma once

#include "common.h"
#include "value.h"
#include "chunk.h"

#define OBJ_TYPE(value)        (AS_OBJ(value)->type)

#define IS_CLOSURE(value)      isObjType(value, OBJ_CLOSURE)
#define IS_FUNCTION(value)     isObjType(value, OBJ_FUNCTION)
#define IS_NATIVE(value)       isObjType(value, OBJ_NATIVE)
#define IS_STRING(value)       isObjType(value, OBJ_STRING)

#define AS_CLOSURE(value)      ((ObjClosure*)AS_OBJ(value))
#define AS_FUNCTION(value)     ((ObjFunction*)AS_OBJ(value))
#define AS_NATIVE(value)       (((ObjNative*)AS_OBJ(value))->function)
#define AS_STRING(value)       ((ObjString*)AS_OBJ(value))
#define AS_CSTRING(value)      (((ObjString*)AS_OBJ(value))->chars)

typedef enum {
    OBJ_CLOSURE,
    OBJ_FUNCTION,
    OBJ_NATIVE,
    OBJ_STRING,
    OBJ_UPVALUE
} ObjType;

struct Obj {
    ObjType type;
    Obj* next;
};

struct ObjString :Obj {
    int length;
    char* chars;
    uint32_t hash;
};

struct ObjFunction :Obj {
    int arity;
    int upvalueCount;
    Chunk chunk;
    ObjString* name;
};

struct ObjUpvalue :Obj {
    Value* location;
};

struct ObjClosure :Obj {
    ObjFunction* function;
    ObjUpvalue** upvalues;
    int upvalueCount;
};

typedef Value(*NativeFn)(int, Value*);

struct ObjNative :Obj {
    NativeFn function;
};

ObjUpvalue* newUpvalue(Value* slot);
ObjClosure* newClosure(ObjFunction* function);
ObjFunction* newFunction();
ObjNative* newNative(NativeFn function);
ObjString* takeString(char* chars, int length);
ObjString* copyString(const char* chars, int length);
void printObject(Value value);

static inline bool isObjType(Value value, ObjType type) {
    return IS_OBJ(value) && AS_OBJ(value)->type == type;
}
```

common.h

```cpp
#pragma once

#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define DEBUG_PRINT_CODE
#define DEBUG_TRACE_EXECUTION

#define UINT8_COUNT (UINT8_MAX + 1)
```

value.h

```cpp
#pragma once

#include "common.h"
#include "object.h"

typedef enum {
    VAL_BOOL,
    VAL_NIL,
    VAL_NUMBER,
    VAL_OBJ
} ValueType;

#define IS_BOOL(value)    ((value).type == VAL_BOOL)
#define IS_NIL(value)     ((value).type == VAL_NIL)
#define IS_NUMBER(value)  ((value).type == VAL_NUMBER)
#define IS_OBJ(value)     ((value).type == VAL_OBJ)

#define AS_OBJ(value)     ((value).as.obj)
#define AS_BOOL(value)    ((value).as.boolean)
#define AS_NUMBER(value)  ((value).as.number)

#define BOOL_VAL(value)   (Value {.type = VAL_BOOL, .as = {.boolean = value}})
#define NIL_VAL           (Value {.type = VAL_NIL, .as = {.number = 0}})
#define NUMBER_VAL(value) (Value {.type = VAL_NUMBER, .as = {.number = value}})
#define OBJ_VAL(object)   (Value {.type = VAL_OBJ, .as = {.obj = (Obj*)object}})

struct Value {
    ValueType type;
    union {
        bool boolean;
        double number;
        Obj* obj;
    } as;
    bool operator==(Value b);
};

struct ValueArray {
    int count;
    int capacity;
    Value* values;

    ValueArray();
    ~ValueArray();
    void write(Value value);
};

void printValue(Value value);
void freeValueArray(ValueArray* array);
```

chunk.h

```cpp
#pragma once

#include "common.h"
#include "value.h"

typedef enum {
    OP_CONSTANT,
    OP_NIL,
    OP_TRUE,
    OP_FALSE,
    OP_POP,
    OP_GET_LOCAL,
    OP_SET_LOCAL,
    OP_GET_GLOBAL,
    OP_DEFINE_GLOBAL,
    OP_SET_GLOBAL,
    OP_GET_UPVALUE,
    OP_SET_UPVALUE,
    OP_EQUAL,
    OP_GREATER,
    OP_LESS,
    OP_NEGATE,
    OP_ADD,
    OP_SUBTRACT,
    OP_MULTIPLY,
    OP_DIVIDE,
    OP_NOT,
    OP_PRINT,
    OP_JUMP,
    OP_JUMP_IF_FALSE,
    OP_LOOP,
    OP_CALL,
    OP_CLOSURE,
    OP_CLOSE_UPVALUE,
    OP_RETURN
} OpCode;

struct Chunk {
    int count;
    int capacity;
    uint8_t* code;
    int* lines;
    ValueArray constants;

    Chunk();
    ~Chunk();
    void write(uint8_t byte, int line);
    int addConstant(Value value);
};
```

When compiling these files along with some other files, I got the following error message

```
Build started...
1>------ Build started: Project: Clox, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>chunk.cpp
1>D:\Ankit\Programming\C++\Clox\object.h(45,8): error C3646: 'chunk': unknown override specifier
1>D:\Ankit\Programming\C++\Clox\object.h(45,13): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>D:\Ankit\Programming\C++\Clox\object.h(51,7): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '*'
1>D:\Ankit\Programming\C++\Clox\object.h(51,7): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>D:\Ankit\Programming\C++\Clox\object.h(51,17): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
1>D:\Ankit\Programming\C++\Clox\object.h(61,15): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>D:\Ankit\Programming\C++\Clox\object.h(61,16): error C2065: 'NativeFn': undeclared identifier
1>D:\Ankit\Programming\C++\Clox\object.h(61,24): error C2513: 'int': no variable declared before '='
1>D:\Ankit\Programming\C++\Clox\object.h(61,24): fatal error C1903: unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping compilation
1>INTERNAL COMPILER ERROR in 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\bin\HostX64\x64\CL.exe'
1>    Please choose the Technical Support command on the Visual C++
1>    Help menu, or open the Technical Support help file for more information
1>Done building project "Clox.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I can't understand why these errors are coming out.

Comment: You do not need to typedef structs in C++ – other than in C `struct S {}` adds `S` to the surrounding namespace directly. Same for enums. All you achieve with these typedefs is making the code harder to read... Apart from you really should produce a [mre]: Throw away step by step any code that does not help to reproduce the error (while doing so you might discover the error yourself already...).

Comment: It looks pretty much as if all of your `Xyz* newXyz(...)` functions actually should be constructors instead.

Comment: I would say that 999/1000 times, you're the one that's wrong and not the compiler. I was just talking about this yesterday. Granted that was with regard to the Standard Library.

Comment: Needing that `ObjType` enum as member in `Obj` usually is a hint to a design flaw in C++. You shouldn't need that, instead you'd rather provide virtual functions as generic interface – which get overriden in the inheriting classes according to what they actually should do. Then from elsewhere you just call these virtual functions without being aware tof the concrete type of the objects.

Comment: The code in the header files looks like C code.  Is this code being ported from C to C++?

Comment: "my own VM implementation in C++"... ok, I see you started implementing in macros. You may later move to C and later to C++? :-) Should not sound harsh but the code is not C++ at all. And if you tag with "c++20" but implement all the stuff in macros, there is simply a big gap in coding!

Comment: I do agree with the OP that this shouldn't cause an internal compiler error. But I'm quite sure that goes away once the other errors are fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a cycle in your include files.

```
object.h  => chunk.h => value.h => object.h
```

So you are getting to a declaration were not all the other types have defined (because `#pragma once` have prevented the includes happening recursively).

You need to break the cycle by using forward declarations in one of these files and removing a #include.

---

It's hard to reproduce the problem without all the files. But I think this can be solved with the following change (in **`value.h`**)

1: Remove this include:

```
#pragma once

#include "common.h"
// -> Remove this line #include "object.h"
```

2: Add a forward declaration:

```
struct Obj;     // Forward declare the class Obj
struct Value {
    ValueType type;
    union {
        bool boolean;
        double number;
        Obj* obj;
    } as;
    bool operator==(Value b);
};
```

The general rule of including from a header file are:

1. Be judicious, only include what you need.
2. If you don't need the full type information, forward declare rather than include.
   i.e. If you only use a pointer then forward declare the class.

This will probably mean that the source file will need an extra include line but that's OK as you normally don't include source file you don't end up with cycles.

---

#### Side-Note there are a couple of other odd things you are doing.

---

Putting `typedef` in-front of all your structures.

```
`typedef struct Value { /* STUFF */} Value;
```

This is C code and not needed in C++. You can simply do:

```
`struct Value { /* STUFF */};
```

and have the same effect.

---

Don't use macros when normal function's can be used.

```
// There is no type checking here.
// This is literally text replacement and can go wrong so easily.
#define IS_BOOL(value)    ((value).type == VAL_BOOL)

// This is type checked.
// Will more than likely be inclined by the compiler so is
// no more expensive.
inline bool isBool(Value const& value) {return value.type == VA_BOOL;}
```

---

Don't use macros when const expression can be used.

```
#define UINT8_COUNT (UINT8_MAX + 1)

static constexpr std::uint8_t UINT8_COUNT = (UINT8_MAX + 1);
```

---

More macro magic that is not correctly type checked:

```
#define BOOL_VAL(value)   (Value {.type = VAL_BOOL, .as = {.boolean = value}})
```

In this case a proper set of constructors will solve this problem. And you don't need to rely on putting the correct macro in place the compiler will check the types and assign use the correct value.

---

Don't create your own array types:

```
struct ValueArray {
    int count;
    int capacity;
    Value* values;

    ValueArray();
    ~ValueArray();
    void write(Value value);
};
```

The standard has some good alternatives already defined and that work very efficiently (`std::vector<>` or `std::array<>` and a few others).